# Prevent macro expansion within levels of indirection

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor, token

The following is a simple program that takes the macro TEST, pastes _NAME to the end of the token, and prints the result.

```
#define TEST 0
#define TEST_NAME "Joe"

#define ID_TO_NAME(id) id ## _NAME

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", ID_TO_NAME(TEST));
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine, however if I introduce a level of indirection, the preprocessor now uses the value of TEST instead of the token "TEST", resulting in the pasted token being 0_NAME instead of TEST_NAME.

```
#define TEST 0
#define TEST_NAME "Joe"

#define ID_TO_NAME(id) id ## _NAME

#define INDIRECTION(id) ID_TO_NAME(id)

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", INDIRECTION(TEST));
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to have it function like the first example (paste the token before expanding the macro) while keeping the indirection?

Comment: I was running into this problem a couple of years ago.  I even drafted a question for SO.  However, I concluded that within my terms of reference, it was not something that could be done in standard C — so the question died, unasked.  I'm pretty sure the same applies to you, assuming that you need the `TEST` macro defined at the point where the `INDIRECTION` macro is used and that you can't build in knowledge about the possible value(s) of `TEST` (so there isn't a sane way to `#undef TEST` while using `INDIRECTION` and then reinstating the previous definition of `TEST` afterwards).

Answer (score 6):

You can forgo using "object-like" macros and give `TEST` an empty parameter list.

```
#define TEST() 0
```

Now `TEST` will never be replaced unless you actively put `()` after it.

---

You can add a bogus `##` operator to every macro that passes the token without expanding it. However, this also requires a bogus parameter as well.

```
#define INDIRECTION(id,_) ID_TO_NAME(id##_)

    printf("%s\n", INDIRECTION(TEST,));
```

Comment: Can you see that the second argument is empty ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス Yes, that's the point. The parameter `_` is bogus because it always must be empty.

Comment: What you did is **totally** useless.

Comment: Very illuminating.

Comment: @StoryTeller can't you see that the second argument is empty too ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス - What I can see is that despite the indirection The program will print "Joe", like the OP wanted.

Comment: @StoryTeller so you don't care about the code it seems. All it matters for you is the output.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス - I care that the OP receives a possible solution to their not easily solvable problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller The best solution would be deleting  `#define INDIRECTION(id,_) ID_TO_NAME(id##_)`  and using `ID_TO_NAME(TEST)`. For better practice.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス - You should write that in an answer. That's a good point.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I'd be happy to address any objection, but please describe what you believe to be wrong and why, rather than repeating that you don't like it. Since OP already wrote that in the question, presumably it's not a viable solution. The key part is, `if I introduce a level of indirection`.

Answer (score 0):

The TEST macro has to be undefined so as to avoid expansion in INDIRECTION macro

```
#define TEST 0
#define TEST_NAME "Joe"

#define ID_TO_NAME(id) id##_NAME

#ifdef TEST
#undef TEST

#define INDIRECTION(id) ID_TO_NAME(id)

#endif
int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", ID_TO_NAME(TEST));
    printf("%s\n", INDIRECTION(TEST));
    return 0;
}
```